# Wrapping all class methods from a foreign package

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I've been trying to find a way to implement a class wrapper that works for any given class for many many hours. All the solutions I've seen either require access to the class definition (the Meta Class solution) or completely ignore `@staticmethod`/`@classmethod` decorators that decorate the class/instance method (the `setattr` solution. E.g. `@staticmethod` decorator is ignored and `self` is still passed to that function as first argument).

How can this be done in Python 2.7?

For example the following foreign class: [SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L587) from `flask_sqlalchemy`. **The end result would be that** I'd be able to call another function before executing the requested function call.

This is my failed attempt:

```
class WithWrapping(object):
    def __init__(self, other_cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other = other_cls(*args, **kwargs)
        self.other_cls = other_cls

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        other_attr = self.other.__getattribute__(attr)
        if callable(other_attr):
            other_attr = getattr(self.other_cls, attr, None)
            if not other_attr:
                other_attr = getattr(self.other, attr, None)

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Do something here prior to function call
            r = other_attr(*args, **kwargs)
            if r == self.other:
                return self
            return r

        return wrapper
    else:
        return other_attr
```

This wouldn't work if you run the following:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = WithWrapping(SQLAlchemy)
class Foo(db.TypeDecorator):
    pass
```

What you'd get is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9813b186f710> in <module>()
      1 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
      2 db = WithWrapping(SQLAlchemy)
----> 3 class Foo(db.TypeDecorator):
      4     pass

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Which I tried debugging but it's quite complicated to follow the many inner calls there.

Comment: Please show us example class with the desired result.

Comment: @KlausD. edited

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% on what you want to achieve, but you can go through the components of an object or a class and wrap them with your own decorator, using things like dir(), callable() and setattr().

```
import functools

class A (object) :
    def __init__( self ):
        pass
    def myop( self, a, b ):
        return a + b

def mydec( fn ):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper( obj, *args, **kwargs ):
        print( "called" )
        return fn( obj, *args, **kwargs )
    return wrapper


for name in dir( A ):
    if not name.startswith( "_" ) : # probably want to think carefully about this!
        attr = getattr( A, name )
        if callable(attr):
            setattr( A, name, mydec( attr ) )
```

results in

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.myop( 1, 3 )
called
4
>>>
```

Is this similar to what you had in mind?

Comment: You understood what I wanted to achieve but this solution is the mentioned `setattr` solution. `@staticmethod`/`@classmethod` decorators and maybe more Python built-in decorators are ignored. Try wrapping `myop` with `@staticmethod` and you'll see.

Comment: You can use the inspect module to determine static methods (inspect.isfunction(fn)) and methods (inspect.ismethod(fn)) but I'm not sure how you identify class methods.  You'd need to branch how you define the new wrapper for each case.